# What is the typical range of a nRF24L01+ module with PCB antenna?

Tags: wireless

I have seen the nRF24L01+ ( http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7&products_id=53&zenid=qa08tp07o8bn54mjpo155e5o1 ) module linked before as a solution for low cost short range communication between MCUs, but finding a reliable range numbers has been difficult.

Does anyone who has experience using these chips in a real environment give an approximate range at the lowest data rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module hasn't got a chip antenna!

Range depends a lot on the relative orientation of the two modules. I can get about 20m indoors, but I haven't experimented with different data rates and power levels.

Comment: Sorry, I meant PCB antenna (I noticed it while going to bed last night).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up ordering a module with the PA and LNA circuit (for my base station) as well as the simple pcb antenna one for my "satellite" device.